# Converting Jquery code to vanilla JS, option value selction and 'one' method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I want to have a Jquery function converted to JS and I am having trouble implementing it.
The Jquery code is commented out, it works exactly as it should.
The main function takes a parameter with the selected option from the select menu(make sure to pick the LeftAndZoom option) and then applies the chosen animation to the container.

This is the main function, I simply cannot figure out how to convert this to JS.

```
$('#imageContainer').removeClass().addClass(x + ' animation').one
('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd 
oanimationend    animationend', function(){
  $(this).removeClass();
});
```

This is the JS I have so far, I've tried many things, but to no avail yet.

```
function testAnim(x) {
var container = document.getElementById("imageContainer").
container.className = "";
container.classList.add(x + ' animation');
this.container.className = "";
}
```

I know this cannot possibly work, but it's still better than what I've tried.

And this is the accompaigning function, to extract the parameter value from the options list:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.triggerAnimation').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var anim = $('.jsanimations').val();
  testAnim(anim);
});

$('.js--animations').change(function(){
  var anim = $(this).val();
  testAnim(anim);
});
});
```

My JS for this is:

```
var trigger = document.querySelector(".triggerAnimation");
var JSanimation = document.querySelector(".js--animations");

trigger.addEventListener('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var anim = JSanimation.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText;
testAnim(anim);
JSanimation.addEventListener("change", function(){
 var anim = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText;
});
```

});

Main issue here is, I don't know how to implement the JS equivalent 'one' method, how to keep "this" context and how to add a callback to the 'one' method

And on top of that, i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null"

Looks like the selection of the option value is not working either.

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/KdobyK

Comment: Please put your attempted code directly in the question.

Comment: Is there a reason you have two hyphens in the class for the second call to `querySelector`? `js--animations` doesn't seem to be in your HTML, but `jsanimations` is. That would account for the TypeError.

Comment: @squint, I had found that code elsewhere a long time ago, and the -- never made sense to me, but it worked with the jquery code. I know, it's odd.But changing it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for making a "one" type of function, here's one way:

```
function bindOne(el, evtTypes, callback, captures) {
  var allEvents = evtTypes.trim().split(/\s+/)

  allEvents.forEach(function(evtType) {
    el.addEventListener(evtType, function boundFn() {
      this.removeEventListener(evtType, boundFn, captures)

      callback.call(this, event)
    }, captures)
  })
}
```

The function defines 4 parameters...

- `el` is the element to be bound
- `evtTypes` is a space separated string of event types to be bound
- `callback` is your event handler
- `captures` indicates if you want bubbling or capturing for this event. You can usually just leave that one off.

Instead of binding your callback directly, it binds a function that immediately unbinds itself on the first event, and then manually invokes your original callback.

The way it keeps the proper `this` value is that it invokes your callback using `.call()`, which lets you manually set the value of `this` in the function being called.

So then you use it like this:

```
function testAnim(x) {
  var el = document.querySelector("#imageContainer")
  el.className = ""
  el.classList.add(x + ' animation')

  bindOne(el, 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd' + 
                                  ' oanimationend animationend', function() {
    this.className = ""
  });
}
```

---

Your `TypeError` is simply because there is no `js--animations` class in your HTML. Should be `jsanimations`.

---

Also, I would probably make your `bindOne` handle browser prefixes for you. That way you only need to pass `'animationend'`, and your function can unbind them all as well.

```
var needsPrefixes = {
  animationend: true
  // can add others as needed
}

var prefixes = ["webkit", "moz", "ms", "o"]

function bindOne(el, evtTypes, callback, captures) {
  var allEvents = evtTypes.trim().split(/\s+/)

  allEvents.forEach(function(evtType) {
    var doPrefixes = needsPrefixes[evtType.toLowerCase()]

    if (doPrefixes) {
      prefixes.forEach(function(prefix) {
        el.addEventListener(prefix + evtType, boundFn, captures)
      })
    }

    el.addEventListener(evtType, boundFn, captures)

    function boundFn() {
      if (doPrefixes) {
        prefixes.forEach(function(prefix) {
          this.removeEventListener(prefix + evtType, boundFn, captures)
        }, this)
      }

      this.removeEventListener(evtType, boundFn, captures)

      callback.call(this, event)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful code, thanks very much. There is still an issue though, i get
"Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined". Yes, I have tried both the js--animations and jsanimations. When i change that to the proper one, I get "Cannot read property 'options' of null".
Is this because the "this" might be out of context?

Comment: @damianocelent: In the event handler bound to the `trigger`, the value of `this` will be the `triggerAnimations` button, not the select list. The `.selectedIndex` should come from `JSanimation`, like... `JSanimation.options[JSanimation.selectedIndex]`

Comment: ...not sure why `".js--animations"` works and `".jsanimations"` doesn't. Use the one that works, I guess.

Comment: I have just set JSanimations as this, but what happens is, I can select the value, the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined".If i take away the this.selectedValue, I get "selected value is undefined".

Comment: Ok, I have now done JSanimation.value; This seems to work, but then when it tries to execute classList.add, I get the following, this one seems codepen specific??
"InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('LeftAndZoom animation') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens."
Tried to remove the space in x + " animation", but still the same.Will try to add x and then the animation class and see what happens, or I'll try className.

Comment: Phew, got it to work.There was a space after the classname in the html, "generated" by random line breaking on codepen...
Good to know, all the "this" is not needed here.
Btw, the getting of the selected value was def wrong, thank you very much for your help, this JS bindOne function is one of the most important things i have learned:-)